# Dictionaries: How to get duplicate input by the user and count how many times it was entered?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
names = []

print("Duplicate names won't be in the list!") # reminder 
while True:
    userInput = input("Enter a name: ")
    if userInput == "": # condition to terminate loop
        print("You've entered these names, duplicated names won't be included")
        print(names)
        break
    elif userInput not in names: # condition to see if input is duplicated
        names.append(userInput) # if satisfied, adds it to the list
    else:
        print("value exists!") # reminder about the value entered is duplicate
```

That's my code so far, I don't know how could I count how many times a specific duplicate value was entered, a Dictionary will solve it a lot of people say but I am not too familiar yet with it. In the output, When the input of names is complete, the console user should be able to search the list for 
names by simply typing the name at the console. The program should output either “Not 
found” or display the name and the number of times it was entered. 
When the searching is complete, the console user should be able to delete names from the list 
by typing the name. If a name is not found, the program should output “Not found”. If a name 
is found then it should be removed from the list and the name is displayed along with a 
“Deleted” message to the user e.g. “Deleted Ted”.

Thank you very much to people that would help!

Comment: *"a Dictionary will solve it a lot of people say but I am not too familiar yet with it"* They are saying it for a reason, that really is the solution to this type of question.

Comment: Maybe you should read this about dictionaries, as it is one of the primary data structures in Python: http://www.diveintopython3.net/native-datatypes.html#dictionaries . There's also the Python documentation itself https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries .

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
c = Counter() #Initialize the counter

print("Duplicate names won't be in the list!")
while True:
    userInput = input("Enter a name: ") #input used to be raw_input in Python 2
    if userInput == "":
        print("You've entered these names, duplicated names won't be included")
        print(c.keys())
        break
    elif userInput not in c: 
        c.update([userInput]) # if satisfied, adds it to the counter. You have to provide a list, hence the [ ]. If you provide a string, it will be broke down into characters.
    else:
        print("value exists!")
```

In order to show a specific count,

```
print c[word]
```

You can also see the most common terms, etc.

However your code forbids that a name be entered more than once, but if you want to count the number of times people enter your name, this is the way to go.

Comment: Sorry, I checked for the existence of Counter in Python 3 but I must have missed something. I remember that raw_input is now input, did I miss something else?

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary consists of a key and a value, a key in a dictionary should always be unique, so unless you have a unique key with every value you use, it wouldn't support duplicate values and will not suit your purposes.

Comment: How could I put names in the dictionary after user input? Plus how will the keys be assigned if only the name is prompted for the user?

Comment: That is my point, where is the name used for? Is it a username? Then you probably have or want to create a userid as well, you can use that as the key.